# R Shiny routing the server calls to appropriate functions

Tags: shiny, shiny-server

I am new to Shiny and trying to build a complete web-app using the shiny modules. I have reviewed the content of
https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html
but still not sure how I would cleanly route the server side requests to a given server function with configuration. e.g.

If the client sends input from a form, which has 2 different actions I am trying to send the processing of the same to a different function. e.g. from the above tutorial -

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    datafile <- callModule(csvFile, "datafile",
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  output$table <- renderDataTable({
    datafile()
  })
}
```

**However, I want to call a different module (callModule) a different function based on input.**

I have reviewed Appsilon's http://blog.appsilondatascience.com/rstats/2016/12/08/shiny.router.html also, but I am not sure if these two approaches are compatible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly some recent developments in the package may help you. `shiny.router` now supports specifying functions explictly that are called dependent on your request URI. I.e.

```
router <- make_router(
  route("/",     root_page,  root_callback),
  route("other", other_page, other_callback),
  route("third", other_page, NA)
)
```

will call the function `root_callback` when you request `/` and will call the function `other_callback` when you request `/other_page` and will call no extra function when you request `/third`.

The functions `root_callback` and `other_callback` should be functions that accept 3 arguments:

```
root_callback <- function(input, output, session) {
   # magic happens here
}
```

Your form input is then then packaged into an the first argument and you can proceed depending on it.

You may want to consult [the example stated in the repo](https://github.com/Appsilon/shiny.router/blob/master/examples/basic/app.R) or [this little demo app](https://github.com/neumanrq/shiny.blueprint).